# How to add an image within a <li>

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists

I want to add an image within a `<li>` without interfering with the size of `<li>`. I want the image to be in the top-left side with 0 margin from the top, bottom and left as shown below:

[image]

I used this HTML code:

```
          <li><img src="image.jpg">text</li>
```

and this CSS:

```
ul li
{
    max-height:52px;
}

ul li img
{
    max-width:52px;
    max-height:52px; 
    margin-top:-15px;
    margin-left:-15px;
    float:left;
}
```

to make it look like that:

[image]

which looks fine for all the screen sizes. But the way of doing it is not professional.

1. What is the best practice to add the image and have a 0 margin from the top, right and left within a `<li>`?
2. In this case I added a max-height for the `<li>` to make it work. Is there a way to do it with a parent-child relationship and make the image interactive depending on the `<li>` height?

Comment: Use an image tag and then apply `float: left`?

Comment: Have you tried giving your image a `width` and `height`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('image.png');
}
```

in your css class

Comment: set image size very small

Comment: This just adds the image. It is not interactive. The margin from the top, bottom, left has to be 0 and the height of the img has to be maximum the height of the li.

Comment: you can do it by changing size margin of picture

Answer (score 0):

I would put images in its own tag (let it be img, div) and style its CSS.

Try using either

```
"float: left;"
"position: relative;"
```

to work with positioning.

Comment: Looking at your 1. and 2. I would look into using javascript, unless you want to do it in css.